# Magento payment method according to product options

Tags: magento, payment

I need to perform the next action when a customer is making the purchase of products:

If there is a product with custom options to display only a method of payment and if no other method.

how to do this ... I'm going crazy

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this event observer

create an extension under app/code/local

Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model
File of extension are `config.xml` under

```
app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/etc
```

and it code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <class>Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model</class>
            </zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
    </models>

    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/observer</class>
                        <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and Observer file code

is

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {


        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();


        if($method->getCode()=='paypal_standard')
        {   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if($this->checkcustomoption()==true){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
            return;
        }
        if($method->getCode()=='free'){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if($this->checkcustomoption()==false){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
public function checkcustomoption(){


//To get your cart object (in session) :

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

//Then, to get the list of items in the cart :

$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

//Then, to get the count for each item :

foreach ($cartItems as $item)
 {  // check  $item->getProduct() give cart item
     $item->getProduct();
    if(your_logic_match){
        return true;
        break;
    }

}

retrun false;
}
}
?>
```

for check and custom option used  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17867/get-custom-option-price-in-order blog Gavin answer

Comment: thanks, but my level of programming and magento knowledge does not allow me to follow the instructions ... I scheduled but really really do not like to face this problem. I've been trying to change by the methods.pthml file but without results (also not recommended that files play clear base)

Comment: I have done what you mention, but nothing is done ... guess not what I should be doing well.

thought that might be more "easy" as it is actually a check when we go to checkout and serious, the option would only be paying budget if there is a product with has_option activated, and conversely if no article has has_option assets would be activated credit card, paypal and bank transfer.